# Consume ENV variables from dockerfile in nuxtjs

Tags: docker, nuxt.js

I am trying to build a nuxtjs app and pack it in a docker image, but for some reason I am not able to use custom env variables from dockerfile no matter what I try.

Here is my code:

```
FROM node:16-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/nuxt-app
WORKDIR /usr/src/nuxt-app
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add git
COPY . /usr/src/nuxt-app/
ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=3000
ENV NUXT_ENV_ACCESS_ID="..."
ENV NUXT_ENV_BASE_URL="..."
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

In `nuxt.config.js` the code looks like below:

```js
publicRuntimeConfig: {
  accessId: process.env.NUXT_ENV_ACCESS_ID,
  axios: {
    browserBaseURL: process.env.NUXT_ENV_BASE_URL
  }
},
privateRuntimeConfig: {
  accessId: process.env.NUXT_ENV_ACCESS_ID,
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.NUXT_ENV_BASE_URL
  }
}
```

When I build and run the docker image, all values are undefined.

How can I consume ENV variables from nuxtjs in this case ?

Comment: when you `docker exec` into the container are the values correct?